# Redirect from child route in react to parent if not authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect the user to the root url if they are not authenticated:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import LoginPage from './components/login/LoginPage';
import DashboardPage from './components/dashboard/DashboardPage';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={LoginPage} />
    <Route
      path='/dashboard'
      render={props => (
        isAuthenticated() ?
          <DashboardPage {...props} /> :
          <Redirect to='/' />
      )}
    />
  </Route>
);
```

I understand why this example doesn't work - App component is expecting 'children' props which are the nested components, but this is rendering them instead; what I don't understand is how to achieve a redirect if `isAuthenticated` returns false  when trying to navigate to `/dashboard` - using `component={...}` doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like you need to have an authentication step somewhere in state above the rendering of this component that determines this and if not authenticated you can use `history` from your `router` and just `this.props.history.push('/')`

Comment: are you using react router v4?

Comment: React router 2.4.0

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, your code seems correct. I would make isAuthenticated a prop tho. So that your component is rerendered when the isAuthenticated prop changes, and then rendering the Redirect if your not authenticated.